# Django collectstatic fails trying to access admin/__init__.py in STATIC_ROOT

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I'd like to serve static files using my web server.

The only one application that is currently installed is `django.contrib.admin` and it contains some static files I'd like to serve.

Everything works just fine with `./manage.py runserver`. Static files are served properly.

But I'm unable to run `./manage.py collectstatic`.

This is how I've configured `django.contrib.staticfiles`:

1. I've set `STATIC_ROOT` to a writable, empty directory. Lets call it `/var/www/SITE_NAME/static/`
2. I've left everything else to its default value:

   ```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
   STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   )
   ```
3. Now when I try to run `collectstatic` within my application folder, I get a very strange error message:

   ```
   $ ./manage.py collectstatic 

   You have requested to collect static files at the destination
   location as specified in your settings file.

   This will overwrite existing files.

   Are you sure you want to do this?

   Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
   Copying '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/media/__init__.py'
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "./manage.py", line 14, in <module>
       execute_manager(settings)
     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
       utility.execute()
     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
       self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
       return self.handle_noargs(**options)
     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 89, in handle_noargs
       self.copy_file(path, prefixed_path, storage, **options)
     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 199, in copy_file
       shutil.copy2(source_path, full_path)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 127, in copy2
       copyfile(src, dst)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
       with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/var/www/SITE_NAME/static/admin/__init__.py'
   ```

Why do I get this error message?

It doesn't seem to make any sense.

Why would it look for `admin/__init__.py` in `STATIC_ROOT` when it is supposed to just copy static files in this directory?

Comment: Well, it was due to bad permissions of the `STATIC_ROOT` directory that I didn't see!  

I still don't understand why such a misleading error message and why does `collectstatic` also copies the `__init__.py` and `__init__.pyc` files.  

Why are those files also copied? They aren't static files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it was due to bad permissions of the STATIC_ROOT directory that I didn't see!